# finding the product of a column where each row is the result of the product of all the above

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table that has days of survival of patients with specific bacteria refereed to in the black as class while the column in the red is the survival percentage out of the total each day. Within each class, I need to multiply column 1-e_1/di by the previous row value of column 1-e_1/di

[image: the data table]

Comment: sorry for the confusion the column named run_perc will be the result of the multiplication of the column named 1-e_1/di and each row will be the result of multiplication of the same row and above  then when we reach another value for the column class we start a new calculation which means we do not multiply by all the above rather only the class with itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this in M code

For the first row of each class it returns the value in 1-e_1/di and for all other rows, multiplies the value in 1-e_1/di by the value of 1-e_1/di on the previous row

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Class"}, {{"data", each 
    let #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type)
    in Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "run_perc", each try [#"1-e_1/di"]*#"Added Index"[#"1-e_1/di"]{[Index]-1} otherwise [#"1-e_1/di"]), type table }}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Grouped Rows"[data], each List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames(_),{"Class","Index"}))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", List,List)
in #"Expanded Data"
```

[image]